# Where does hadoop mapreduce framework send my System.out.print() statements ? (stdout)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to debug a mapreduce script, and without going into much trouble tried to put some print statements in my program. But I cant seem to find them in any of the logs.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Actually stdout only shows the `System.out.println()` of the **non-map reduce** classes.

The `System.out.println()` for map and reduce phases can be seen in the logs. Easy way to access the logs is

*http://localhost:50030/jobtracker.jsp->click on the completed job->click on map or reduce task->click on tasknumber->task logs->stdout logs.*

Hope this helps

Comment: The same approach applies also using Oozie under Hue. Oozie schedules MR2 map jobs, but does not show logs properly. To see them, you should go under jobtracker.jsp.

Comment: JobTracker doesn't existe in Hadoop 2

Comment: I found mine on: http://localhost:9870/logs/userlogs/

Answer (score 26):

Another way is through the terminal:

**1)** Go into your *Hadoop_Installtion* directory, then into  *"logs/userlogs"*.
**2)** Open your *job_id* directory.
**3)** Check directories with *_*m_** if you want the mapper output or *_r_*  if you're looking for reducers.

**Example**: In Hadoop-20.2.0:

```
> ls ~/hadoop-0.20.2/logs/userlogs/attempt_201209031127_0002_m_000000_0/
log.index   stderr      stdout      syslog
```

The above means:
Hadoop_Installation: ~/hadoop-0.20.2
job_id: job_201209031127_0002 
_m_: map task , "map number": _000000_

**4)** open *stdout* if you used "system.out.println" or *stderr* if you used "system.err.append".

PS. other hadoop versions might have a sight different hierarchy but they're all should be under $Hadoop_Installtion/logs/userlogs.

Answer (score 16):

On a Hadoop cluster with `yarn`, you can fetch the logs, including stdout, with:

```
yarn logs -applicationId application_1383601692319_0008
```

For some reason, I've found this to be more complete than what I see in the webinterface. The webinterface did not list the output of `System.out.println()` for me.

Comment: Thanks for giving answer for hadoop2. can you tell me why I am getting this error after executing that command? `Logs not available at /tmp/logs/hadoopuser/logs/application_1441282624447_3854` and `Log aggregation has not completed or is not enabled`

Comment: The job history interface corresponding to hadoop 2.7 also does not list System.out.println for me whereas the command provided here does.

Answer (score 8):

to get your stdout and log message on the console you can use apache commons logging framework in to your mapper and reducer.

```
public class MyMapper extends Mapper<..,...,..,...> {

    public static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyMapper.class)

    public void map() throws Exception{
        // Log to stdout file
        System.out.println("Map key "+ key);

        //log to the syslog file
        log.info("Map key "+ key);

        if(log.isDebugEanbled()){
            log.debug("Map key "+ key);
        }

        context.write(key,value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After most of the options above did not work for me, I realized that **on my single node cluster**, I can use this simple method:

```
static private PrintStream console_log;
  static private boolean node_was_initialized = false;
  private static void logPrint(String line){
    if(!node_was_initialized){
      try{
        console_log = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("/tmp/my_mapred_log.txt", true));
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        return;
      }
      node_was_initialized = true;
    }
    console_log.println(line);
  }
```

Which, for example, can be used like:

```
public void map(Text key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
      logPrint("map input: key-" + key.toString() + ", value-" + value.toString());
      //actual impl of 'map'...
    }
```

After that, the prints can be viewed with: `cat /tmp/my_mapred_log.txt`.
To get rid of prints from prior hadoop runs you can simple use `rm /tmp/my_mapred_log.txt` before running hadoop again.

notes:

- The solution by Rajkumar Singh is likely better if you have the time to download and integrate a new library.
- This could work for multi-node clusters if you have a way to access "/tmp/my_mapred_log.txt" on each worker node machine.
- If for some strange reason you already have a file named "/tmp/my_mapred_log.txt", consider changing the name (just make sure to give an absolute path).