# Where to look for the console output of hive UDF in Amazon EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, amazon-emr

I am creating a UDF in java that can be called in Hive Queries, In the UDF I put in System.out.prinln(msg) hoping to output something in the console. It works as expected in my local workplace, but when deployed to amazon EMR, the stderr log file don't show any output message from my UDF function. Where do I look for the file that contains my message output?

Comment: how do you access the stderr log on your local machine?, are you redirecting hive's output? I have println statement in my UDF but I get nothing on the console.

Answer (score 2):

If Hive submitted the query to M/R then any output will be captured in your submitted job console output. See [Where does hadoop mapreduce framework send my System.out.print() statements ? (stdout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207238/where-does-hadoop-mapreduce-framework-send-my-system-out-print-statements-s). For the EMR specific flavour of M/R please reffer to [View Log Files](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-manage-view-web-log-files.html):

> Amazon EMR does not automatically archive log files to Amazon S3. You must configure this when you launch the cluster...
>
> When Amazon EMR is configured to archive log files to Amazon S3, it stores the files in the S3 location you specified, in the /JobFlowId/ folder, where JobFlowId is the cluster identifier.

Note that Hive can also run queries locally.