# Hadoop map() function not being called

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

My map() function doesn't seem to be called at all during my codes execution and I can't understand why. Below is my Job's class...

```
public class MyHadoopJob extends Configured implements Tool{

static class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text>{

    public MyMapper(){
        System.out.println("Mapper init!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                       org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text>.Context context)
            throws java.io.IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("MAP!");
        context.getCounter("mygroup", "jeff").increment(1);
        context.write(key, value);
    };
}

@Override
public int run(String[] strings) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf = MYOBJ.getHadoopConf();
    this.setConf(conf);

    Job job = new Job(conf, "MyJob");
    job.setJarByClass(MyHadoopJob.class);
    job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(strings[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(strings[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        log.info("Progress -> " + job.mapProgress());
        Thread.sleep(15000);
    }

    return 0;
    }

}
```

I'd really appreciate some help figuring out why does the map() class or indeed the class initialization never get called?

Comment: What do you see when you run the job does it complete?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're using `System.out.println` statements to debug Hadoop jobs.

The problem with this approach is that `println` statements don't go to your console. They go to the job logs. That's why you don't see "Mapper init!" in your console.

You need to look at the job logs.

To quote a great man (and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5785472/1240162)):

> Easy way to access the logs is
>   http://example.com:50030/jobtracker.jsp->click on the completed
>   job->click on map or reduce task->click on tasknumber->task
>   logs->stdout logs.