# Issue with logging in hadoop

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, apache-commons-logging

I am running a mapreduce task on a local hadoop 2.20 cluster setup on ubuntu 13.04. As per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207238/where-does-hadoop-mapreduce-framework-send-my-system-out-print-statements-s/5785472#5785472) on S.O. the output to my system.out.println() statements should go into my $HADOOP_INSTALLATION/logs/userlogs folder. But even after my task finishes , the folder remains empty.

I have tried logging using

1) System.out.println()

2) Logger l = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WordCountPartitioner.class); l.info("###");

But both have no effect on the logs folder. I also tried to use the `LogFactory` class but my compiler kept giving an error. Do I need to add any extra jars for it?

Thanks !!

Comment: Is the print command reachable, or is it perhaps inside an if / for block?

Comment: @vefthym,, the print code is directly inside the setup() of my mapper class and since it gives NullPointerException at the beginning of my reduce task i.e. at .createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:390) , I am not sure if it is even getting called.